# I receive the following error 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression' when adding data

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have the following error but I am not sure why I am getting this error. When I attempt to add data to the database I receive this error.

**Data type mismatch in criteria expression.**

The code I am working on is below. Can anyone please help? Thanks

```
 Private Sub RefreshData()
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'open connection
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Item ID as [Item ID], " & _
                                         "Item Name as [Item Name], " & _
                                         "Item Type as [Item Type], " & _
                                         "Quantity as [Quantity], " & _
                                         "Min Shelf Stock as [Min Shelf Stock], " & _
                                         "Purchase Price as [Purchase Price], Note " & _
                                         " From Product ORDER BY Item ID", cnn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    'fill data to datatable 
    da.Fill(dt)

    'offer data in data table into datagridview
    Me.dgvData.DataSource = dt

    'Close the connection
    cnn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            'The line of code below opens the connection to the database if it isnt open
        cnn.Open()
        End If

    cmd.Connection = cnn
    'Check whether to add new or update
    If Me.txtItemID.Tag & "" = "" Then
        'Add new 
        'The line of coding below adds data to table
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Product ([Item Id], [Item Name], [Item Type], [Quantity], [Min Shelf Stock], [Purchase Price], [Note]) VALUES (@id, @name, @iType, @quantity, @minshelfstock, @price, @note)"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtItemID.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtItemName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iType", cboItemType.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", txtQuantity.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@minshelfstock", txtMinShelfStock.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", txtPurchasePrice.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@note", txtNote.Text)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Else
        'Update data in the table 
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Product " & _
                    " SET [Item ID]=" & Me.txtItemID.Text & _
                    ", [Item Name]='" & Me.txtItemName.Text & "'" & _
                    ", [Item Type]='" & Me.cboItemType.Text & "'" & _
                    ", [Quantity]=" & Me.txtQuantity.Text & "" & _
                    ", [Min Shelf Stock]=" & Me.txtMinShelfStock.Text & "" & _
                    ", [Purchase Price]=" & Me.txtPurchasePrice.Text & "" & _
                    ", [Note]='" & Me.txtNote.Text & "'" & _
                    " WHERE [Item ID]=" & Me.txtItemID.Tag
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End If
    'Refresh data in list
    RefreshData()
    'Clear the form
    Me.btnClear.PerformClick()

    'The code below closes the connection to the database
    cnn.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Product_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\inventorysystem.mdb"
    '
    'Get the data into a list
    Me.RefreshData()
End Sub

Private Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
    'check for the selected item in list
    If Me.dgvData.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If Me.dgvData.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim intItemID As Integer = Me.dgvData.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Item ID").Value
            'Get the data from database followed Item ID
            'Open the connection
            If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                cnn.Open()
            End If
            'Get the data into the datatable
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Product " & _
                                                  " WHERE Item ID=" & intItemID, cnn)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)

            Me.txtItemID.Text = intItemID
            Me.txtItemName.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Item Name")
            Me.cboItemType.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Item Type")
            Me.txtQuantity.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Quantity")
            Me.txtMinShelfStock.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Min Shelf Stock")
            Me.txtPurchasePrice.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Purchase Price")
            Me.txtNote.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("Note")
            '
            'Hide the ID to be edited in TAG od txtItemID in case ID is changed 
            Me.txtItemID.Tag = intItemID
            'Change the add button to update 
            Me.btnAdd.Text = "Update"
            'Disable the Edit button
            Me.btnEdit.Enabled = False
            'Close the connection
            cnn.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    'Check for the selected item in the list
    If Me.dgvData.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If Me.dgvData.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim intItemID As Integer = Me.dgvData.SelectedRows(0).Cells("Item ID").Value
            'Open the connection 
            If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                cnn.Open()
            End If

            'Delete data 
            Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
            cmd.Connection = cnn
            cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Product WHERE Item ID" & intItemID
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            'Refresh the data 
            Me.RefreshData()

            'Close the connection
            cnn.Close()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: THe first thing that jumps off the page are the aliases to Item ID. Item Name, etc. What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the [AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. This method creates parameters and their datatype. However to do so, it looks at the datatype of the value passed as second argument. If this value is a string (like in your case where you pass always the Text property of your textboxes) then it build a parameter of type [OleDbType.LongVarWChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or similar. Of course this is not what your database expects for one or more of the fields that you want to update.

You need to check the datatype of your fields and pass a parameter of similar datatype, applying a conversion to the string value of your textbox.

For example, if the price field is of type numeric decimal then you need to write

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", Convert.ToDecimal(txtPurchasePrice.Text))
```

Comment: The data types are: Item ID = Number,
Item Name = Text,
Item Type = Text,
Quantity = Number,
Min Shelf Stock = Number,
Purchase Price = Currency,
Note = Text,

Comment: Then you need to convert the TextBoxes values for these fields to the appropriate numeric value.

Comment: Could you please write the code for this as I am new to VB

Comment: Just use Convert.ToInt32(textbox.text) around the parameter value for a number fields of type integer/long in access and Convert.ToDecimal for number fields of type decimal or Convert.ToDouble for number fields of type double precision or Convert.ToSingle for number fields of type single precision

Comment: It comes up with this error:  Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: One or more of your textbox doesn't contain a valid number. Please use the debugger to step line by line in the code where you convert the numbers and find the failing line

Answer (score 0):

Might be due to the Quantity datatype.

Try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57hkzhy5.aspx)

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id",  SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtItemId.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@name",   SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = txtItemName.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@iType",   SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = cboItemType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@quantity",  SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtQuantity.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@minshelfstock",  SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtMinShelfStock.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@price",  SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtPurchasePrice.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@note", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = txtNote.Text;
```

Not sure if it's what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Will I be able to use this as I am using MS Access

Comment: It should, since you're only adding the type of the value you want to pass to the command.

Comment: It is giving me the error 'End of statement expected'

Comment: Can you debug on the function and see where it pops the error message?